# How can I share Grafana dashboard with json data in php web application?

Tags: grafana, grafana-api

Using HTTP API to share dashboard from Grafana into another PHP web application's dashboard gives me JSON data using curl

Referred http://docs.grafana.org/http_api/dashboard/ and used GET /api/dashboards/uid/:uid

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_PORT => "3000",
  CURLOPT_URL => here comes grafana dashboard url to share,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: Basic YWRtaW46ZHluRWtvZGU=",
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) { 
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err; ?>      
<?php } else {
  echo $response;
}
```

In the response get JSON data.
How can I use this json to get particular Grafana dashboard access on my web application?

Comment: It is not clear which API did you use.

Comment: I refered http://docs.grafana.org/http_api/dashboard/ and used 
GET /api/dashboards/uid/:uid

Comment: That is only dashboard model, that is not shared dashboard.

Comment: yes its a dashboard model, but what if I need to import live data from grafana dashboard into my web application dashboard.Is there any way?

Comment: Sure, implement Grafana code (frontend/backend) in your web application and then you will be able to reuse that model in your web app.